# Give an example of nonunitary representation of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: representation-theory

Give an example of nonunitary complex representation of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Could anyone give me a hint for solving this problem ?

Comment: What is a unitary representation?

Comment: A matrix representation of $\Bbb Z$ has the form $n\mapsto A^n$ where $A$ is a nonsingular matrix. Not all nonsingular matrices are unitary; indeed not all nonsingular matrices are similar to unitary matrices.

Comment: Ok.  I also looked it up, and apparently $e^{ik}$ might be unitary.   What if we put $r\neq1$ in front?   Does this have any chance?

Comment: The representation $T:\Bbb{Z} \to \operatorname{GL}(2,\Bbb{C}), \ \ z \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\z & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is nonunitary.